# Use jQuery to Check if Link exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a pagination div that contains links to the `previous` page `<span id="previous"><a href="www.site.com/page/1" >Previous</a>`, and to the `next` page. On the first page, there will not be any link to the previous page.

Now I have 2 image buttons with front and back arrows. If the user clicks on these buttons, jQuery will take the link from the pagination div as mentioned above and redirect the user to these links. However if the pagination link does not exist like on the first page, clicking the `previous button` will not do anything.

**My Code:**

```
//img has id = info_rightclick_left

$("#info_rightclick_left").click(function() {
                    if($("#pagination_previous")) {
                        window.location  = $("#pagination_previous a").attr("href");
                    } else {
                        alert("NOO");
                    }
                });
```

The problem now is that it seems like whether or not `#pagination_previous` exists, clicking the image still redirects the user. In this case, on page 1, the user gets redirected to `undefined`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
$("#info_rightclick_left").click(function() {
                    if($("#pagination_previous").length) {
                        window.location  = $("#pagination_previous a").attr("href");
                    } else {
                        alert("NOO");
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

the answer in your question itself! just check for undefined like so:

```
$("#info_rightclick_left").click(function() {
   if($("#pagination_previous a").attr("href") !== "undefined") {
      window.location  = $("#pagination_previous a").attr("href");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($("#pagination_previous").length > 0) {
```

jQuery returns a list of captured elements, if it doesn't find any it will return an empty list, but still a list